# Where hadoop stores the files for reading and writing through HDFS programmatically

Tags: hadoop

I am using pseudo distributes mode setup on my machine and created below program in my eclipse IDE:

This program just merges input files to a single file in HDFS.

```
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataInputStream;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataOutputStream;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileStatus;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;

public class PutMerge {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        Configuration conf = new Configuration();

        FileSystem hdfs = FileSystem.get(conf);

        FileSystem local = FileSystem.getLocal(conf);

        Path inputDir = new Path("/home/temp/input");
        Path hdfsFile = new Path("MyMergeFile.txt");
        try {
            FileStatus[] inputFiles = local.listStatus(inputDir);
            FSDataOutputStream out = hdfs.create(hdfsFile);
            for (int i = 0; i < inputFiles.length; i++) {

                System.out.println(inputFiles[i].getPath().getName());

                FSDataInputStream in =

                local.open(inputFiles[i].getPath());
                byte buffer[] = new byte[256];
                int bytesRead = 0;
                while ((bytesRead = in.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                    out.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);

                }

                in.close();

            }

            out.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        }

    }

}
```

The program ran successfully,but where the `MyMergeFile.txt` gets generated?

I tried to check using command `./hadoop fs -lsr /` but the file is not present in output of this command.

**Update:**

When trying to check in HDFS, I am getting error message:

```
./hadoop fs -ls hdfs://localhost:50070/MyMergeFile.txt
ls: Call to localhost/127.0.0.8:50070 failed on local exception: java.io.EOFException

./hadoop fs -ls hdfs://localhost:50030/MyMergeFile.txt
ls: Call to localhost/127.0.0.8:50030 failed on local exception: java.io.EOFException
```

Comment: Try to print absolute path to the output file with `System.out.println(hdfs.getFileStatus(hdfsFile).getPath());` command.

Comment: @AlexeyShestakov, Yes I can see the file in my eclipse project now. But how can I pass it to Hadoop so I can see it as part of HDFS? I am new to Hadoop so may be I am asking very simple question.

Comment: You should get path to your file, something like `hdfs://server:port/MyMergeFile.txt`. What the output of command `./hadoop fs -ls hdfs://server:port/MyMergeFile.txt` ?

Comment: @AlexeyShestakov, Thanks for responding, I am getting error when I ran the command. Please check my updated question.

Answer (score 1):

```
FileSystem hdfs = FileSystem.get(conf);
```

This line does not return HDFS, but the configured FS. This *may* be HDFS. But you say you're running from Eclipse and you do not seem to have a NM running on 50070. I suspect you are not running in pseudo-distributed mode but instead you run on standalone mode. Your FS is probably local raw filesystem anchored in `/tmp`.

If you'd be running in [pseudo-distributed mode](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/SingleCluster.html#Pseudo-Distributed_Operation) you would remember the steps of configuring the NM name dir (`dfs.namenode.name.dir`) and the DN data dir (`dfs.datanode.data.dir`).

Comment: Thanks Remus, I have started all the services using `start-all.sh` command of hadoop and can also see the ports `50030` and `50070` are up. So my NM is up. also using `jps` command I can see the services are up. But I am new to Hadoop and just learning by following a tutorial. After running the java program in my question I was expecting to see the file in HDFS but it is not present. Can you please tell me how can I fix it?

Comment: Are you sure your Eclipse IDE job was submitted to this 'cluster', not run in Standalone mode?

Comment: I guess my eclipse is in standalone as the file is not present in HDFS, can you please tell me how to submit the file to cluster?